# SQL Compare 2 columns data and show matching

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, compare

I'm having trouble identifying entries in my DB.

I need it to show me when `CallRef` and `PersonRef` are the same and appear more than once in the table. I don't want to see a count of them, I need to see which call refs they are.

Example below highlighted:

```
CallRef PersonRef   Leader
222359  5894    0
222360  3212    0
222361  8743    0
222362  5894    1
222362  5894    0
222364  3983    0
222365  9863    0
*222365 5894    1*
*222365 5894    1*
222368  5894    0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other answer (+1), same constructs and return but includes PersonRef in output as you can have duplicate callrefs, but not CallRef/PersonRef combo.  You'd want to be able to differentiate the rec above the starred (222365  9863 from the starred dupes 222365 5894) and this would do that if needed.

```
SELECT  CallRef,PersonRef 
FROM UrTable
GROUP BY CallRef,PersonRef 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query should select the entries you want using the GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT constructs:

```
SELECT CallRef FROM table
GROUP BY CallRef, PersonRef
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```